# Nav bar disappears in all browsers when using css position: fixed;

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi I've been messing around with the code, and **have looked at similar posts** on here but the examples/solutions don't work.

I have a nav bar which I would like fixed to where it is while the user scrolls down.  Seems simple enough?  Except that when I use:

```
position: fixed;
```

It makes the nav bar appear briefly then disappear.

When I use z index...it moves the navbar down and to the left!?

Here's my isolated code:

Thanks.

style.css

```
html {
 min-height:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
background-color:#000;

}
body {
  background-color:000;
  font-family:"Verdana", sans-serif; color:#c4c4c4; font-size:16.0px; line-height:1.19em;
  color:#000;
  font-weight:100;
  margin:0px;
 min-height:100%;
  width:100%;
}


header .nav {
  float:right;
  position: fixed;
 margin-top: 60px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        right bottom,
        color-stop(0, #000000),
        color-stop(1, #71399E)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #000000 0%, #71399E 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #000000 0%, #71399E 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #000000 0%, #71399E 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #000000 0%, #71399E 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #71399E 100%);
}
```

Index.html

```
  <header>





    <div class="wrap">
      <!-- logo -->

       <a href="#!"><img class="logo" src="img/history_00.png" /></a>
  <h7>Building lasting relationships<h7>



<ng-controller = "demoCtrl">

<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">



      <li ng-class="{active: isState('home') }">
        <a ui-sref="home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li ng-class="{active: isState('form') }">
        <a ui-sref="form">CANDIDATES</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('clients') }">
        <a ui-sref="clients">CLIENTS</a>
      </li>
       <li ng-class="{active: isState('aboutus') }">
       <a ui-sref="aboutus">ABOUT US</a>
      </li>

      <li ng-class="{active: isState('training') }">
        <a ui-sref="training">TRAINING</a>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <h3 class="text-muted">          </h3>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: is this by any chance fixed above a slider?

Comment: Have you played with the z-index value?

Comment: No slider.  Just a partial view.

yes played with the z-index value.  Tried Values between 1 and 20.  No effect.

Comment: Seems like you're not giving us everything necessary, I put the code in jsfiddle and it worked fine. Is there any javascript changing the css or html? Is this code placed inside of a relatively position element?

Comment: I tested the code as well and it worked just fine in Chrome and IE11 as presented above.

Comment: Seems to work for me in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bI1f94vPwji68eiHUEbq?p=preview I'm not sure how different it is from your actual page.

Comment: Here's my jsfiddle with all the css and all of index.html


http://jsfiddle.net/yb3a5nma/

Comment: What is the purpose of the full-background div? Is there a reason you have that on the DIV and not as part of the body?